# Does this approximation always overestimate?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, approximation

So, I'm working on a method that calculates $\cos\theta : \theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ using geometric methods, and I'm trying to work out the error of the approximation. I have a wonderful estimate for the approximation if I know that the following always produces an overestimate.

We have a $h_0 := \frac{\theta}{2^k}$, where $k$ is an arbitrary fixed positive integer, which produces the sequence $h_n := h_{n-1}\sqrt{4 - h_{n-1}^2} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. These values are approximating $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2^{k+1-n}}$, which is the length of the chord of an arc of a circle with angle $\frac{\theta}{2^{k-n}}$. It is obvious, from observation that $h_0$ is the arc length of the circular arc with angle $\frac{\theta}{2^k}$, and thus is an overestimate for $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2^{k+1}}$.

My dilemma is that empirical evidence shows that $h_n$ overestimates $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2^{k+1-n}} \quad \forall n \in [0, k-1] \cap \mathbb{Z}$, and in some cases for $h_k$ as well. However despite varied attempts I have been unable to prove that this is the case. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try to improve $h_0$ by using the next terms of the Taylor series, for instance $h_0=2(2^{-k-1}θ-\frac16·2^{-3k-3}θ^3)$ should give a lower but closer value than the true sine values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your considerations, and introducing a distinction between the exact and approximate angle,
$$
h_0=\fracθ{2^k}=2\sin\fracϕ{2^{k+1}}
$$
you get for the exact angle of the iteration 
\begin{align}
ϕ&=2^{k+1}\arcsin\frac{θ}{2^{k+1}}
\\
&=
2^{k+1}\left(\frac{θ}{2^{k+1}}+\frac16\frac{θ^3}{2^{3k+3}}+…+\binom{2n}{n}\frac{θ^{2n+1}}{2^{nk+n}4^n(2n+1)}+…\right)
\\
&= θ+\frac{θ^3}{6·2^{2k+2}}+O(2^{-4k})
\end{align}

Which means that
$$
h_{k+1}=2\sinϕ=2\sin\left( θ+\frac{θ^3}{6·2^{2k+2}}+…\right)
$$
will be slightly larger than $2\sin θ$.

---

Of course, 
$$
h_k=2\sin\fracϕ2=\frac{\sinϕ}{\cos\fracϕ2}
$$
will be systematically larger than $\sinϕ$ as $\cos\fracϕ2<1$.

Comment: This appears to be perfect for my needs, though there is a small issue in that $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2^{k+1-n}} < 2\sin\frac{\phi}{2^{k+1-n}}$ only holds, as far as I can tell, because sin is an increasing function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. However it could be possible that $\phi$ falls outside this range, how would you deal with this. One way that sprngs to me is to restrict the domain of $cos$ to just $[0, \frac{\pi}{4})$, I'm not sure how I would go about this though.

Comment: The obvious way to deal with the sign change at $\frac\pi2$ is to make the iteration 2 dimensional, i.e., iterate the cosine values explicitly, to avoid having square roots in the iteration.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how this helps. The iteration that I use in the program uses the update $h_{n+1}^2 :=h_n^2(4-h_n^2)$, and I never need to root it but how does this avoid the issue of $\phi$ exceeding $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The real question is, why is this an issue? What do you want to achieve? Explore the properties of this recursion? Compute trigonometric values?

Answer (score 0):

You need the fact that for $x \gt 0, \sin x \lt x$.   You can prove this by using the Taylor series and alternating series theorem, which says that (once the terms are decreasing) the error is the same sign as and smaller than the first neglected term.  As the Taylor series for $\sin x$ is $x-\frac {x^3}6 + \dots$ we have $\sin x \lt x$ for $0 \lt x \le 1$.  For larger $x$ (not your issue here) you can just use $\sin x \le 1$